# How to store CHATBOT's unanswered questions in a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, chatterbot

i'am newbie to *python* and building a chatbot using **chatterbot** library and i want to store those questions which are asked by users which chatbot could not answers(i mean storing unanswered questions) in a *text* file or *database* so that we can put their answers later.
here is the code of **chatterbot** constructor

```
self.chatbot = ChatBot(
            "GUI Bot",
            storage_adapter="chatterbot.storage.SQLStorageAdapter",
            logic_adapters=[{
                'import_path': 'chatterbot.logic.BestMatch',
                'default_response': 'I am sorry, but I do not understand.',
                'maximum_similarity_threshold': 0.75
} ]
        )
```

here is full code of class

```
class TkinterGUIExample(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Create & set window variables.
        """
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.chatbot = ChatBot(
            "GUI Bot",
            storage_adapter="chatterbot.storage.SQLStorageAdapter",
            logic_adapters=[{
                'import_path': 'chatterbot.logic.BestMatch',
                'default_response': 'I am sorry, but I do not understand.',
                'maximum_similarity_threshold': 0.75
} ]
        )


        for files in os.listdir('C:/Users/HP/Desktop/FYP BOT/training_data/'):
            con=open('C:/Users/HP/Desktop/FYP BOT/training_data/'+files,'r').readlines()
            trainer = ListTrainer(self.chatbot)
            trainer.train(con)
        self.title("Chatterbot")

        self.initialize()
```

Answer (score 1):

There must a be way to know which logic adapter was used in chatterbot or, if none of them was used. The easiest way I can think around it is to use `default_response`.

Set `default_response = '-2E-'` or something else. Next, add an if else condition to see if the value of `str(bot.get_response(userText))` is equal to `-2E-`. If they are a match that means none of the logic adapters was used and no match for user input was found.

No logic adapter used means it is an input for which there is no answer. You can now append the user input which is stored in `userText` to a text file.

Code:

```
## initialize chatter bot
bot = ChatBot(
    'robot',
    storage_adapter='chatterbot.storage.SQLStorageAdapter',
    preprocessors=[
        'chatterbot.preprocessors.clean_whitespace',
    ],
    logic_adapters=[
        {
            'import_path': 'chatterbot.logic.BestMatch',
            'default_response': '-2E-',
            'maximum_similarity_threshold': 0.90,
            'statement_comparison_function': chatterbot.comparisons.levenshtein_distance,
            'response_selection_method': chatterbot.response_selection.get_first_response
        },
        'chatterbot.logic.MathematicalEvaluation'
    ],
    database_uri='sqlite:///database.db',
    read_only=True
)
```

Below is sample logic for usage within code. You should modify this logic with you own requirements.

```
## Open a file to write unknown user inputs
with open("unanswered.txt", "a") as f:

    ## Loop and get user input
    ## Check to see if none of the logic adapters was used
    if str(bot.get_response(userText)) == "-2E-":
        f.write(userText)
        return "Sorry, I do not understand."
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a variable to open a txt file for writing and loop every line you want to add from a list with formatting like below:

```py
file1 = open('your_txt_file.txt', 'w')
for questions in question_list:
    file1.write('{}\n'.format(questions))
file1.close()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir i have applied this but shows error that "**questio_list is not defined**"  i have used **default_response** instead of that but still not working and where to put this code i mean within **chatbotterbot** perameters or out of there?

Comment: you need to create a text file with the same name as in your for loop and keep it in the same directory as your .py file